# RS232 via API set hardware control flux

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, vb6, serial-port

I have this code that work without problems:

```
' Declare the local variables that you will use in the code.
Dim hSerialPort, hParallelPort As IntPtr
Dim Success As Boolean
Dim MyDCB As DCB
Dim MyCommTimeouts As COMMTIMEOUTS
Dim BytesWritten, BytesRead As Int32
Dim Buffer() As Byte


        hSerialPort = CreateFile("COM1", GENERIC_READ Or GENERIC_WRITE, 0, IntPtr.Zero, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, IntPtr.Zero)

' Retrieve the current control settings.
     Success = GetCommState(hSerialPort, MyDCB)

     MyDCB.BaudRate = 9600
     MyDCB.ByteSize = 8
     MyDCB.Parity = NOPARITY
     MyDCB.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT

' Reconfigure COM1 based on the properties of the modified DCB structure.
     Success = SetCommState(hSerialPort, MyDCB)

     '
```

I need to set the hardware control flux

how I can do it ?

Thank you !!

Comment: There isn't much point in writing code like this.  The SerialPort class takes care of it.  It has a Handshake property.

Answer (score 0):

You can set flow control via the  SerialPort.Handshake property; you also have fairly direct access to the hardware using the properties DTREnable, RTSEnable, DSRHolding, and CTSHolding.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you refer to RTS/CTS based flow control. There are several DCB parameters for this, fOutxCtsFlow, fOutxDsrFlow, fRtsControl, fDtrControl, plus for software-based flow control fInX, fOutX.

Only the right combination of settings for all of these will work as intended. In our software we have four different options, and this is how our code sets the related DCB values

Usually we set (in c++)

```
   DCBptr->fOutxDsrFlow = 0;
   DCBptr->fDtrControl = DTR_CONTROL_ENABLE;
```

Then we decide if and what flow control to use:

```
 // Flow control settings
  switch(flowControl)
   {case 1:  // HW flow control
      DCBptr->fOutxCtsFlow = 1;
      DCBptr->fRtsControl = RTS_CONTROL_HANDSHAKE;
      DCBptr->fInX = 0;
      DCBptr->fOutX = 0;
      break;
    case 2: // SW (XON/XOFF) flow control
      DCBptr->fOutxCtsFlow = 0;
      DCBptr->fRtsControl = RTS_CONTROL_DISABLE;
      DCBptr->fInX = 1;
      DCBptr->fOutX = 1;
      break;
    case 3: // RTS On Send (RS485 Transceiver Mode) 
      DCBptr->fOutxCtsFlow = 0;
      DCBptr->fRtsControl = RTS_CONTROL_TOGGLE;
      DCBptr->fInX = 0;
      DCBptr->fOutX = 0;
      break;
    default: // no flow control
      DCBptr->fOutxCtsFlow = 0;
      DCBptr->fRtsControl = RTS_CONTROL_DISABLE;
      DCBptr->fInX = 0;
      DCBptr->fOutX = 0;
      break;
   }
```

Hope this helps, 
Oliver